# How to replace given index in String with Dictionary value in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, indexing

The instructions are to replace certain characters within a string to the corresponding value in the dictionary.

Here is my code:

```
word = input()
password = ''
wordDict = {
    
    'i': '!',
    'a': '@',
    'm': 'M',
    'B': '8',
    'o': '.',
    
}

for i in range(len(word)):
    if word[i] in wordDict.keys():
        word.replace(word[i], wordDict.get(word[i]))
        i += 1
    else:
        i += 1

print(word)
```

The problem with my code is that nothing about the given password is changing nor does it seem to be iterating through the for loop.

Comment: A few hints... It's cleaner to iterate characters of the string like `for c in word`. No need to fuss with an index variable `i`. Lookup `c` in your dictionary using `dict.get` as you're doing, but make use of the default argument. `wordDict.get(c, c)` so that any character not in the dictionary is mapped to itself. Finally, it's probably nicer to build a new string rather than modify `word` in place. For that, you have the `"".join()` method on the string class. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with this line:

```
word.replace(word[i], wordDict.get(word[i]))
```

Strings in Python, as well as many other languages, are *immutable*, meaning you can't edit the string.

The function you're calling (`str.replace`) doesn't replace the character in the string, it returns a new `str` with the character replaced.

The easiest, though naive if you want this to work efficiently, solution is to replace it with this line:

```
word = word.replace(word[i], wordDict.get(word[i]))
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks so much, I appreciate the thorough explanation as well.

Comment: @svnrod No worries, good luck with python :).

Remember that you can accept an answer once you're satisfied, so that the question is marked as having been answered.

Comment: yep, I just accepted it. Appreciate the good luck!